# Get Facebook referal in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing chrome extension. In the Facebook post in my feed I see link to the external website in format 
`https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tangerine.ca%2Fen%2Flandin…tM7QqqESiaNgGMvpibHdshV98FB21NJuKkSoM-OQfdcd2HuAMi6JS_MMgb00SdAYDaQZ2mIN-K`, but I want to get link in format 
 `http://www.tangerine.ca/?utm_campaign=Facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com`

How I can convert first link to the second? Is it possbile? Thanks

Comment: And why would you want to get a result that is different from the URL Facebook originally linked to?

Comment: @CBroe I need that params `utm_source`, `utm_campaign` etc

Comment: @CBroe I noticed one intersting thing. First url converted to the second one, if I hover on this link, but it doesn't  work if I try to trigger event "mouseover" on this link with JS in chrome extension code. It doesnt converted

Comment: _“I need that params utm_source, utm_campaign etc”_ - and where exactly in the first URL do you think you see those …?

Comment: @CBroe nowhere, but as I write above "First url converted to the second one, if I hover on this link, but it doesn't work if I try to trigger event "mouseover" on this link with JS in chrome extension code". Maybe there are other ways to convert it? I'm not familiar with Facebook.

Comment: I don’t see those utm parameters added when hovering those links, that only ever shows the original shared URL.

Comment: @CBroe yes, original only. Url with utm params I could found earlier in mouseover attribute, but now it doesnt appear on element with class="_52c6" Probably something changed on FB